# Ada concatenate Integer with String

Tags: type-conversion, ada, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate a string with an integer to create unique file names.

```
    I: Integer := 1;
    Base: String := "file";
    Suffix: String := ".data";

    -- Want to create file name as "Base + I + Suffix"
    file_name := "file1.data"
```

How do I do this?

Would it be easier to use the Integer to index into an array of integer characters/strings and then concatenate all three together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
file_name : String := Base & Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim(Integer'Image(I), Ada.Strings.Left) & Suffix;
```

`Integer'Image(I)` returns `I` as a string.  If `I` is nonnegative, this function returns a string with a space as the first character; the `Trim` function removes leading spaces if any.

And it would not be easier to use `I` as an index into an array of strings.  For one thing, in an  `array` of `String` in Ada, all the `String` elements have to be the same length, which wouldn't work if `I` could be `>= 10`.  You'd have to make it an array of access-to-String or an array of `Unbounded_String`.  In any case, you'd have to set the array up, probably using a loop that uses `Image` very much like the above code, so it wouldn't be any easier.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding Brian's answer a bit:

Adding this function:

```
function "&" (Left  : in String;
              Right : in Integer) return String is
begin
   return Left & To_String (Right);
end "&"
```

will allow you to write:

```
File_Name : constant String := Base & I & Suffix;
```

Answer (score 2):

ajb's answer is authoritative, so I can only add a couple of points:

1) you can tidy up the mess in the middle by abstracting it out into a function and write 
`Filename := "Base" + To_String(I) + "Suffix"`

```
function To_String(I : Integer) return String is
begin
   return Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim(Integer'Image(I), Ada.Strings.Left);
end To_String;
```

2) it's often struck me as curious that text I/O has overloaded operations Get,Put (via generic packages) for Integer and other non-text datatypes while string manipulation does not. However it would be easy to generalise To_String to a generic integer type.